# For ActivityResultContracts, what is the alternative for In-App Updates?

Tags: android, android-contacts, in-app-update

I am restructuring my code to use ActivityResultContracts, and I've been able to recreate the old way of doing things with `onActivityResult` by passing in "codes" with my Intents and just passing them back from the called activity. Everything is working fine, but how would I manage to do that with App Updates, even the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#status-callback) is still using onActivityResult to check for app updates.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at it for the past few days, it does not seem like it is possible to forgo using `onActivityResult`; the cancel response is only returned to that method. If you have a listener setup to check for resumed downloads, you will get a response there (as `onResume` is called when the calling activity is moved back to the foreground) but you only get that an update is available and the install status is unknown (which coincidentally is the same value as cancelled, and you can't do anything there as you get the same values on the initial call to check for an update). I don't see the point in deprecating a method you're still required to use, but oh well.